# Stability of a fixed point

Tags: dynamical-systems, fixed-point-theorems, stability-in-odes

Determine the stability of all the fixed points of the following functions:

So basically I understand how to find fixed points and whether they are attracting/repelling...but I am confused on how to check their stability, and also confused about what to do if the derivative =1 (see part a)

a. $$S(x)=\sin x$$
$$x=\sin x$$

$1$ fixed point at $x=0$

$$\mbox{Fix}\{S\}=\{0\}$$

$$S(x)=\sin x$$
$$S'(x)=\cos x$$
$$S'(0)=\cos 0$$
$$S'(0)=1$$

And this is where I am stuck? Since $1$ is inconclusive right? Also I don't understand
lyapunov's stability theorem/if I even need to use that here...

b. $$f(x)=2sin(x)$$
$$x=2sin(x)$$
$$\mbox{Fix}\{S\}=\{0,±a\}$$
$$a≈1.895$$
$$f(x)=2sin(x)$$
$$f'(x)=2cos(x)$$
$$f'(0)=2cos(0)$$
$$f'(0)=2>1$$ 
x=0 is repelling
$$f'(±a)=2cos(±a)$$
$$f'(±a)=\sqrt{4-a^2}<1$$
x=±a is attracting

So...does that mean it is unstable?

c. $$T(x)=tan(x)$$
$$x=tan(x)$$
$$\mbox{Fix}\{S\}=\{0,±a\}$$
$$a≈4.49$$

$$T(x)=tan(x)$$
$$T'(x)=sec^2(x)$$
$$T'(0)=sec^2(0)$$
$$T'(0)=1$$
so??? it is inconclusive? or what is the next step?

$$T(x)=tan(x)$$
$$T'(x)=sec^2(x)$$
$$T'(±a)=sec^2(±a)$$
$$T'(±a)=sec^2(±4.49)$$
$$T'(±4.49)=20.556>1$$

x=a is repelling

d. $$E(x)=e^x$$

no fixed points

e. $$F(x)=\frac{1}{4}e^x$$
$$x=\frac{1}{4}e^x$$
$$\mbox{Fix}\{S\}=\{0.357,2.153\}$$

$$F(x)=\frac{1}{4}e^x$$
$$F'(x)=\frac{1}{4}e^x$$

$$F'(x)=\frac{1}{4}e^x$$
$$F'(0.357)=\frac{1}{4}e^{0.357}$$
$$F'(0.357)=0.357<1$$

x=0.357 is attracting

$$F'(x)=\frac{1}{4}e^x$$
$$F'(2.153)=\frac{1}{4}e^{2.153}$$
$$F'(2.153)=2.153>1$$

x=2.153 is repelling

So...one attracting fixed point and one repelling fixed point. As for the stability...I am not sure?

Comment: @Amzoti  I think? a fixed point iteration  with x=sinx...in that steP I set x=S(x) to find the fixed points, is that not what I am supposed to do?

Comment: @Amzoti Judging from some of his other questions, I believe he's studying iterative dynamics, rather than continuous dynamics. So that $x_0$ is a fixed point of $f$ if $f(x_0)=x_0$. The point is attractive if $|f'(x_0)|<1$.  I think a lot of the results look good or close, though it could be written more clearly. The tan function has infinitely many fixed points, though.